# how to rename endpoints with express gateway?

Tags: express-gateway

i am trying to build an api that consists of different services and i want to everything to start with /api/ path. like the following below.

i want https://thirdparthy/comments to be routed as /api/comments on express gateway. what is the correct confirmation?

```
http:
  port: 4000
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  users:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/api/users'
  comments:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/api/comments'
serviceEndpoints:
  users:
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
  comments:
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  users:
    apiEndpoints:
      - users
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: users 
              prependPath: false
              ignorePath: false
  comments:
    apiEndpoints:
      - comments
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: comments 
              prependPath: false
              ignorePath: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use the `rewrite` policy to change the target url or simply configure the proxy policy accordingly:

`- proxy:
  - action:
    serviceEndpoint: comments
    prependPath: true
    ignorePath: false`

This should do the job.

Cheers,

V.

Comment: You might want to provide more details, otherwise it's hard for me to help. Feel free to open a new question.